# PHP mail() from and replyto headers are ignored

Tags: php, email, lamp, sendmail

I have a problem on a server for which the additional headers get ignored.

Code to reproduce:

```
$toEmail="customer@domain.com";
$subject="subject";
$message="this is a message";
$fromEmail="Customer Service <customerservice@domain.net>";
$replyToEmail="Customer Service <customerservice@domain.net>";
mail("$toEmail", $subject, $message, "FROM: $fromEmail","-f$replyToEmail");
echo "mail sent";
```

The from address ends up being: 
    customerservice@domain.net.prod3.domain.net

prod3.domain.net is the name of the server, so it concatenates the from address and the machine name.

Server is LAMP running Centos5.

Thanks!

Cam

Comment: Is `$replyToEmail`'s domain served by the same server?

Comment: This question is now [duplicated on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/334228/).

Answer (score 0):

1) Please enclosed the email name with double quote, e.g. $fromEmail = "\"Customer Service\" "

2) Please change the "FROM" to "From". For example, "From: $fromEmail"